# Expected value of orthogonal projection $X^{+}X$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m<n$, be a random matrix where the rows $x_i$ ($i=1,...,m$) are sampled i.i.d. from Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and covariance $\Sigma$, i.e. $x_i\sim N(0,\Sigma)$.

How to calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X^{+}X]$ where $X^{+}$ is the Moore–Penrose inverse of $X$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: why for the special case it holds that $\bf E[X^+X]=\frac{m}{n}I$, I am very confused, can you give the reference of this property?

Comment: It is in fact incorrect for general $m$ and $n$, fixed.

Comment: Can you provide some examples to show that this conclusion is incorrect? Do you mean $$E[X^{+}X]=\frac{m}{n}I$$ does not hold for $m>n$ or this statement has not been proved yet? We test this statement in matlab, and it seems correct when $m\leq n$.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that it is correct only for large $m$ and $n$, but it should be also correct for small values. Just use the SVD of $X$ to show it.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\det\Sigma\ne0$. Then the random matrix $X$ is of rank $m$ almost surely (a.s.). So, a.s. the [Moore--Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Rank_decomposition) of $X$ is $X^+=X^\top(XX^\top)^{-1}$ and hence
$$X^+X=X^\top(XX^\top)^{-1}X.$$

It appears that $EX^+X=EX^\top(XX^\top)^{-1}X$ cannot be expressed in closed form, even in the fully specified case when $m=2$, $n=3$, and $\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Indeed, in this case $\Sigma=A^\top A$ for $A:=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$. So,
for the rows $x_i$ of $X$ we can write $x_i=z_i A$, where the $z_i$'s are iid rows of iid standard normal random variables $z_{i,j}$.

In the image of a Mathematica notebook below, the expression of even the $(1,1)$-entry (P11) of the matrix $P:=X^+X$ in terms of the $z_{i,j}$'s looks very formidable, and Mathematica cannot do anything for the expectation of P11, leaving it unevaluated after working on it for more than an hour (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why $X^{\top}(XX^{\top})^{-1}X=Z^{\top}(ZZ^{\top})^{-1}Z$ ? Thank you.

Comment: @Edward : That equality was incorrect, and the answer has been changed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is feasible if $\Sigma$ is diagonal (but not scalar) ?

Comment: @Edward : I have done similarly for the diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ with $1,1,4$ on the diagonal. Then the expression for the orthoprojector is not substantially simpler, and Mathematica still cannot do anything with the expectation.